# Parallel and A transport-level error

Tags: .net, sql-server, parallel-processing

Im facing this following problem. 
Im using parallel to read lines from a file (being each line an complex object inside the code) and insert them on the DB.

From time to time, i get the error: "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server."

So, i was reading that i should restart IIS to avoid this error, but my doubt is if there is something i can configure on Parallel to avoid this problem?

Is there a connection in this error between Parallel and SQL ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Transport-Level errors occur when there is either a network or server outage, and the client loses its connection to the SQL Server.

There isn't really anything in your app that you configure to prevent this.   You could maybe write an error handler that takes steps to keep trying the connection until it is back up.